# SQL Server left join behavior

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I'm having an issue with left joins.  Every time I think I understand them I run across an issue. In the following query I'm only trying to return records where PracticeTypeName = 'Facility.'  I know for a fact that PracticeTypeID's 13328 and 502 exist in both Table A and Table B, so there shouldn't be any NULL values in this instance.  PracticeTypeID = 502 is PracticeTypeName = 'Billing', so it should not be returned.  I'm using a left join to account for other cases where the ID's don't match.

```
    Select Memberid, locationname, practicetypeid, practicetypename
    From A
    Left Join B
    On A.PracticeTypeId = B.PracticeTypeID
    And A.PracticeTypeName = 'Facility'
```

This query returns the following result

```
    MemberID     LocationName     PracticeTypeID    PracticeTypeName
    10            UHC                13328               Facility
    10            TV                  502                NULL
```

But if use this query instead:

```
    Select Memberid, locationname, practicetypeid, practicetypename
    From A
    Left Join B
    On A.PracticeTypeId = B.PracticeTypeID
    Where A.PracticeTypeName = 'Facility'
```

I get the following result, which is what I'm looking for:

```
    MemberID     LocationName     PracticeTypeID    PracticeTypeName
    10            UHC                13328               Facility
```

I thought that with left joins you would use the following, otherwise the left join just becomes an Inner Join.

```
   On A.PracticeTypeId = B.PracticeTypeID
   And A.PracticeTypeName = 'Facility'
```

Why is this left join doing the reverse of what I thought a left join should do?

Comment: You could use also an `INNER JOIN` which would also only return matching rows. The `LEFT JOIN` "becomes an inner join" only if you use the keyword `INNER`. Both join types can have one or multiple join-conditions.

Comment: Perhaps your tables are actually views? Your posted queries should return the same resultset (though the order of rows might be different since you have no order by clause). So absent a mistake (e.g., a different database), what you see should not be possible. To double check - which is a habit you should develop - replace the where clause with one based on PracticeTypeID. You should get the same 2 rows.

Comment: The queries aren't equivalent. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The WHERE clause will filter on your entire result set, whereas adding your condition to the JOIN will only join on those rows. Since it's a LEFT JOIN, putting the condition in the JOIN clause will still return rows that have no match, with NULL for the joined table's columns.

The WHERE looks at your results and says "Which rows have Facility?", and returns those.

Comment: What confuses me here is "putting the condition in the JOIN clause will still return rows that have no match, with NULL for the joined table's columns."  In this case there is a match between A.PracticeID = B.PracticeID, as both tables have ID = 502.  So shouldn't there not be a NULL value in this instance?  There is a match and then I'm filtering out those records that <> 'Facility' with the AND clause.

Comment: It sounds like "Facility" is not the PracticeTypeName for 502? If that's the case, it's working as I described. If not, I'm confused.

Comment: "Billing" is the PracticeTypeName for 502, which I'm trying to filter out.  Table A and Table B both have Billing 502.

Comment: Yep, so when you add the "= 'Facility'" predicate to your JOIN clause, you're saying "Return to me all rows from A, and give me any matching data from table B. If there's no match in table B, then give me NULL". If you take that out and put it into the WHERE, You're saying "Return all from A, matching data from B, NULLs where there is no match. Then get rid of rows where PracticeTypeName <> 'Facility'

Comment: I understand what you're saying with "If there's no match in Table B then give me null."  But in this case there is a match.  I would think the result would show 2 records, one with PracticeTypeName = 'Facility' and another = 'Billing' since Table B does have a matching 'Billing' record.  And then the "AND" clause would remove the entire 'Billing' record.  I know a WHERE clause filters on the entire result set, but I thought the "AND" here would work since there actually is a match between the tables with the 'Billing' record, therefore not returning a NULL from Table B.

Comment: I see what you're saying. The key piece to remember here is that within the JOIN clause, ALL of your conditions COMBINED determine if there is a match between the two tables. Since you're joining on PracticeTypeID AND Name = 'Facility', there is no match. Both of those conditions are being used to determine if there's a match.

Comment: That makes sense.  I didn't realize all the conditions combined determine if there is a match.  Thank you for clarifying that!